# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Blogs#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I am trying to finish out a CRUD action for **Blog**

When I run the the following code, I get the error `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Blogs#index`

Here is my controller

```
before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def find_post
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @blog.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

And in my view, I have the link `<%= link_to "Update Post", edit_blog_path(@blog) %>`

And like I said, when I run the code, I get the error `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Blogs#index`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where ist located that `link_to`, in show or index ?

Comment: @7urkm3n it's in index

Comment: if its index, r u sure u have `@blog` instance ? i think u have `@blogs`. to edit just try to use `edit_blog_path(blog)` like this.

Comment: Could you post your whole view code not just the `link_to....`? I am just wondering why you used `@blog` not just `blog` on this code `<%= link_to "Update Post", edit_blog_path(@blog) %>` you posted above.

Comment: And also, is this link `<%= link_to "Update Post", edit_blog_path(@blog) %>` you posted above is on `Blog#index`? Please also add the `index` method in your controller.